# "The given text", or how should students or scholars refer to the text they are given in an exam?

Tags: formality, academic-writing

In an exam situation students are often given a text which they have to summarize, analyze, you name it. Often they start their answers "The given text ... deals with" or "The text at hand ... is about".
Are these the most natural expressions that come to mind in academic writing? I heard or read somewhere that just writing "This text is about.." would be fine. Can you confirm that this would meet academic usage, or does it sound trivial?

Comment: Most people (like me) would refer to [*The cited text...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+given+text%2CThe+cited+text&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) rather than *The given text...* But they're both perfectly valid, so neither choice could possibly "cost you exam marks".

Comment: Or simply "the text".

Comment: "This text is about x" is fine. this: if they have a print-out of it with the question underneath.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, I didn't know Google had this corpus function!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Often in academic writing we use different usages than in casual conversation. Because of this, it's easy to get the idea that "fancier is better" in academic writing. But *good* writing is still clear, and as simple as possible. All we have to do in academic writing is avoid certain usages that are frowned on. "Sounding trivial" isn't really the problem as long as the content isn't trivial; academic writing doesn't need to have a somber or lofty tone. Sometimes we might get feedback that the tone of our academic writing is wrong, like if we say "This text is, like, totally original!" But the problem here is simply that we're using casual colloquial patterns that aren't welcome.

The only thing that might be wrong about saying "this text" is that it might not clear what "this text" refers to. But "the given text" or "the text at hand" would have the same problem! In an exam we're sometimes given a passage without explanation of what it is or where it came from, so this is about the best we can do. If we're writing a research paper it might be better to actually call the text by name, especially the first time in a paragraph.